# Handling multiple POST attachments with GNU cgicc

Tags: c++, post, cgi, httprequest

I'm trying to send a POST request containing multiple binary files to a HTTP server. The server interprets the request using [cgicc](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/).

For a single file, it works like this:

```
cgicc::Cgicc cgi;
cgicc::const_file_iterator file;
file = cgi.getFile("file_1");
if(file != cgi.getFiles().end())
{
      std::stringstream stringStream;
      file->writeToStream(stringStream);
      //do whatever with stringStream
}
```

Now, let's say that I want to post multiple files and I don't know the names of the attachments in advance in order to call `cgi.getFile("file_x")` for each file, is there any way to iterate over all of them? For the GET parameters, I can do this:

```
cgicc::Cgicc cgi;
const std::vector<cgicc::FormEntry> &formElements = cgi.getElements();
for (std::vector<cgicc::FormEntry>::const_iterator i = formElements.begin(); i != formElements.end(); ++i)
{
    //process each (*i)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out (it was obvious, but poorly documented):

```
cgicc::Cgicc cgi;
const std::vector<cgicc::FormFile> &formFiles= cgi.getFiles();
for (std::vector<cgicc::FormFile>::const_iterator i = formFiles.begin(); i != formFiles.end(); ++i)
{
    //process each (*i)
}
```